# How to use SED regex in toml config file?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to create a custom prompt for `zsh` theme `starship` which has an API configurable via a `.toml` file...

The code which I'm trying to use at the moment is:

```
[custom.vtex]
command = "cat $HOME/.config/configstore/vtex.json | grep account | sed -n 's/.*\:.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p'"
description = "My custom prompt"
files = [".vtexignore"]
style = "fg:red"
```

The .json I have is:

```
{
    "env": "prod",
    "_nextFeedbackDate": "2021-08-17T12:43:59.194Z",
    "account": "example",
    "workspace": "workspace",
    "_lastUsedWorkspace": "master",
    "login": "email@email.com",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkEwRkQ4NDgzNTFG...",
    "_lastUsedAccount": "other-account",
    "apps": {
      ...
    }
}
```

The cat & grep alone returns this:

```
    "account": "example",
```

And what I'm trying to accomplish is extract everything but `example` to show it in my prompt. Problem is I'm not sure if it cannot be done in a `.toml` file but I get this error:

```
[ERROR] - (starship::config): Unable to parse the config file: invalid escape character in string: `:` at line 14 column 83
```

And if I add/remove scaping characters then no more errors show but `sed` returns nothing.

---

**EDIT:**
Added de `.json` as example.
I succesfully solved this with your help but changing David response because I still needed to escape double quotes since the command in `.toml` was between them.
Finally I did this, note that I needed account and workspace, didn't mention it earlier cause I thought I'd be able to solve it by myself (but probably someone can make it in a more efficient/fashion way):

vtex_prompt.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
account=$(sed -n -E '/^[[:blank:]]*\"account"/s/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]\"([^\"]+)\",$/\1/p' $HOME/.config/configstore/vtex.json)
workspace=$(sed -n -E '/^[[:blank:]]*\"workspace"/s/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]\"([^\"]+)\",$/\1/p' $HOME/.config/configstore/vtex.json)
echo "$account/$workspace"
```

starship.toml

```
[custom.vtex]
command = "zsh ~/vtex_prompt.sh"
description = "VTEX Prompt"
files = [".vtexignore"]
```

Comment: Try ``sed -n 's/.*:.*\"\\(.*\\)\".*/\\1/p'`` inside the command.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the contents of `vtex.json` and show the exact expected output of the command you want help writing given that input file so we can show you how to do whatever it is you want (and it will not involve cat+grep+sed!). I say "whatever it is" because "extract" is ambiguous (so never say "extract" in this context, say "print" or "delete", whichever you mean) - at first I thought you wanted to print only `example` but now I think you want to print everything **except** `example` so idk...

Comment: @EdMorton you are right, edited now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract `"example"` (without the quotes) from your string above, regardless of the leading whitespace in the line with a substitution and backreference. Using *extended* regex with the `-E` option will cut down on the number of escapes with `'\'` needed. Using `[[:blank:]]` to match whitespace will match all types of whitespace.

Putting it together you can do:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]"([^"]+)",$/\1/'
```

This presumes your `cat`/`grep` output ends with the `','` without trailing whitespace. (adjust if it does)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo '    "account": "example",' |
> sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]"([^"]+)",$/\1/'
example
```

Let me know if that is what you intended or if I misinterpreted your need. Also let me know if you have further questions about the `sed` expression.

As [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) notes, you should be able to get rid of the `cat` and `grep` and use `sed` alone with:

```
sed -n -E '/^[[:blank:]]*"account"/s/^[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]"([^"]+)",$/\1/p'
```

Where `-n` suppresses the normal printing of pattern-space and `/^[[:blank:]]*"account/` before the `s/find/replace/` locates the line beginning with   `"account"..` before extracting and printing. That would make things a bit more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much, with all this information I've accomplished what needed!